# Local linux interaction with EC2 (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a linux shell script ( script.sh ) with command lines ( CLI ) from AWS to access the account and establish connection with the instance through ( EC2 Instance Connect Endpoint ). After the connection is established with the instance ( EC2 ), which command ( CLI - AWS ) do I use within the shell script to send any linux command to the instance and get the output of the result in the terminal? Below is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Step 1
echo "Connecting to the account ( AWS ) . . ."
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="00000000000"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="000000000000"
sleep 3
echo "Connection established."

# Step 2
# Get the return in json format from the instances
access_json=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-east-1)
# Extract the InstanceId key value using jq
instance_id=$(echo "$access_json" | jq -r '.Reservations[0].Instances[0].InstanceId')

# Step 3
# Establish connection to the instance
echo "Connecting to the instance ( EC2 ) . . ."
aws ec2-instance-connect ssh --instance-id $instance_id --connection-type eice -- region us-east-1
echo "Connection established."

# Step 4
# Which command (CLI-AWS) do I declare to send linux commands to the instance (EC2) 
through the established connection ?
```